# Android: Wifi comunication

Tags: android, wifi

I have an customized &rooted Android device with WiFi opened,but not connect to any rooter. Now I have my iPhone which has connected to RooterA, Is there any way that my phone send udp packets and the Android device can receive that packets? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear from your Q, anyway here's how I interpret that.

- To communicate (send/receive) UDP (layer-4), the two hosts must first establish an IP connection (layer-3). In your case, as long as the Android phone is not connected to anything, it's impossible for it to receive any UDP datagrams sent from the iPhone.
- Given Android and iPhone are in the same network, it's certainly possible to write UDP client/server to send/receive UDP datagrams (packets) between these two platforms.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I think if any way to get the packets without connection, just like in Monitor Mode or Promiscuous Model? To receive "air packets "?